# memcached+mysql cluster maximum memory

Tags: mysql, memory, mysql-cluster

I'm deploying a system with memcached and mysql cluster.
The command line is:

```
memcached -E lib/ndb_engine.so -e "connectstring=maddy:1186;role=dev"
```

I can't specify the `-m` argument since I used `-E` and `-e`.

My questions are:

1. Is the maximum memory 64M? If so, how can I change it? Any solution for about 1G-2G memory requirement?
2. Are there any more stable versions than memcached-1.6.0_beta1.tar.gz?

Comment: 84M? Is this 1995 or 2012? :)